# Update records only once with LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, outer-join

I am trying to UPDATE Table A with records in Table B based on a LEFT OUTER JOIN based on two columns of data. So, for example, the JOIN from Table A might be USA-4 to match Table B's USA-4. Returning a result of XYZ to a different column. The problem I am having is the Table B contains multiple USA-4's and as a result Table A appears to be updating more than once. Is there a way to fix this? A different JOIN type?

Comment: Instead of joining Table B directly use subquery with `DISTINCT or GROUP BY` and then join

Comment: post the actual update

Comment: Does the GROUP BY query have to be pasted into a Table?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tablea a
SET USA-4 = (SELECT distinct USA-4 FROM tableb b WHERE a.id=b.id)
```